# Unable to get value in defined variable from database

Tags: php, html

```php
echo '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xm-12 mb-5">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src='.$category_image.' alt="Card Image Cap" 
                 style="height:300px; object-fir:contain">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">'.$category_name.'</h5>
                <p class="card-text">'.substr($category_desc,0,50).'.....</p>
                <p>'.$category_price.'/-</p>
                <a href="details.php?details_id='.$category_id.'" class="btn 
                        btn-primary">
                   Add to Cart
                </a>
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>';
```

I am using below line of code to get value from $category_id into details_id

```
<a href="details.php?details_id='.$category_id.'" class="btn 
              btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
```

on echo details_id show nothing but echo of $category_id showing the value.

Can anyone tell where I am doing wrong.

Thanks

not able to get value in details_id from $category_id

Comment: In details.php, If you use `echo $_GET["details_id"];` , what do you see ?

Comment: `on echo details_id show nothing`...where / when are you echoing that? Please show the code which is actually causing the problem.

Comment: "details.php"
<?php include ("partials/connect.php"); ?>
<?php include ("partials/header.php"); ?>
 
<?php

$id=$_GET['details_id'];
$sql="Select * from 'cloths' where $category_id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                $category_id=$row['category_id'];
                $category_name=$row['category_name'];
                $category_desc=$row['category_desc'];
                $category_price=$row['category_price'];
                $category_image=$row['category_image'];
?>

Comment: "index.php"

               
            <img class="card-img-top" src='.$category_image.' alt="Card Image Cap" 
            style="height:300px; object-fir:contain">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">'.$category_name.'</h5>
              <p class="card-text">'.substr($category_desc,0,50).'.....</p>
              <p>'.$category_price.'/-</p>
              <a href="details.php?details_id='.$category_id.'" class="btn 
              btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>

Comment: Warning: Undefined array key "details_id" in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php on line 26

Warning: Undefined variable $category_id in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php on line 27

Warning: Undefined variable $con in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php on line 28

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_query(): Argument #1 ($mysql) must be of type mysqli, null given in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php:28 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php(28): mysqli_query(NULL, 'Select * from '...') #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommerce\partials\details.php on line 28

Comment: Please [edit] your question when you have code and other important information to share. As you can see, it's almost unreadable like that in the comments, and it should not be buried away dowm here anyway.  Thanks

Comment: Also, remember we can't see your line numbers, so please point out exactly where the errors start

Comment: Error:

<?php include ("./partials/connect.php"); ?>
<?php include ("./partials/header.php"); ?>

$id=$_GET['details_id'];
$sql="Select * from 'cloths' where $category_id=$id";

Comment: Again, please **edit your question**, don't keep adding this stuff to the comments! See also [ask]. There is an [edit] button right there just under the little blue tags.

Comment: Anyway, `var_dump($_GET);` will tell you what was in the GET variables sent to this script. `details_id` evidently was not one of the variables. So please check exactly what URL is used to call this script when you get the error.